# write access violation with c++ libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm trying to create c++ code that download data from some URLs, but it's throwing a write access violation:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef WIN32

#endif
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

static const char* urls[] = {
  "http://www.example.com",
  "http://www.example1.com",
};

#define MAX_PARALLEL 10 /* number of simultaneous transfers */
#define NUM_URLS sizeof(urls)/sizeof(char *)

static size_t write_cb(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buffer)
{
    ((std::string*)buffer)->append((char*)ptr, nmemb);
    return nmemb;
}

static void add_transfer(CURLM* cm, int i, int* left)
{
    CURL* eh = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_URL, urls[i]);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, urls[i]);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &write_cb);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_multi_add_handle(cm, eh);
    (*left)++;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURLM* cm;
    unsigned int transfers = 0;
    int msgs_left = -1;
    int left = 0;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    cm = curl_multi_init();

    /* Limit the amount of simultaneous connections curl should allow: */
    curl_multi_setopt(cm, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, (long)MAX_PARALLEL);

    for (transfers = 0; transfers < MAX_PARALLEL && transfers < NUM_URLS;
        transfers++)
        add_transfer(cm, transfers, &left);

    do {
        int still_alive = 1;
        curl_multi_perform(cm, &still_alive);


        CURLMsg* msg;
        int queued;
        CURLMcode mc = curl_multi_perform(cm, &still_alive);

        if (cm)
            /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
            mc = curl_multi_poll(cm, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);

        if (mc)
            break;

        do {
            msg = curl_multi_info_read(cm, &queued);
            if (msg) {
                if (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) {
                    /* a transfer ended */
                    fprintf(stderr, "Transfer completed\n");
                }
            }
        } while (msg);
     
        if (left)
            curl_multi_wait(cm, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);

    } while (left);

    curl_multi_cleanup(cm);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its crashing on the line:

```
_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize = _Old_size + _Count;
```

The full error message is:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
this was 0x7FF7941D39D0.
```

How can I make this code download each Url data without any error?

Comment: you've set `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to `&write_cb` making `((std::string*)buffer)` unwise

Comment: Especially since `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` is set to a `const char *`. Casting a `const char *` into a `std::string` always ends in tears.

Comment: I don't see line `_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize = _Old_size + _Count;` in the code.

Comment: In `static size_t write_cb(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buffer)`, are you _absolutely_ sure that `buffer` points to `std::string`, and `ptr` points to `char` array, which not `const` and has `nmemb` elements? Especially `buffer` being `std::string` seems quite dubious, since you don't create any `std::string` anywhere in the code, and I'd imagine `curl` does not either.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the pointer passed to `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` isn't being used https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PRIVATE.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `write_cb()` callback, you are expecting the `buffer` parameter to point at a `std::string` object, but in `add_transfer()` you are setting `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to point at `write_cb` itself rather than at a `std::string` object.

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct url_info {
  const char* url;
  std::string data;
};
static url_info urls[] = {
  {"http://www.example.com", ""},
  {"http://www.example1.com", ""}
};
static const int NUM_URLS = sizeof(urls)/sizeof(urls[0]);

static size_t write_cb(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buffer)
{
    size_t result = size * nmemb;
    static_cast<std::string*>(buffer)->append(static_cast<char*>(ptr), result);
    return result;
}

static void add_transfer(CURLM* cm, int i, int* left)
{
    ...
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_URL, urls[i].url);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &urls[i].data);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, &urls[i]);
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    while ((msg = curl_multi_info_read(cm, &queued)) != NULL) {
        if (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) {
            /* a transfer ended */

            url_info *info;
            curl_easy_getinfo(msg->easy_handle, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, reinterpret_cast<char**>(&info));
            // use info->url and info->data as needed...

            std::cerr << "Transfer completed from " << info->url << ", bytes received: " << info->data.size() << "\n";
        }
    }
    ...
}
```